# OCaml readline with history support

Tags: io, ocaml, readline

I want something like Python's [`readline`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/readline.html) but in OCaml. I'm writing an OCaml program that takes in input like a shell or REPL would, and I would like to add history that is prompted with the arrow keys. Is there any library or built-in that provides this functionality?

Comment: [ocaml-linenoise](https://github.com/ocaml-community/ocaml-linenoise)

Comment: yes, there are lots of such libraries, Zed, lineoise, lambda term, to name a few. You can use `opam search`, browse available packages at http://opam.ocaml.org/packages/, or even google for "ocaml readline"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [ivg's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55739377/ocaml-readline-with-history-support#comment98177253_55739377), `opam search readline` shows:

- [linenoise](https://github.com/ocaml-community/ocaml-linenoise) -- this looks to offer the specific functionality you're looking for with very little overhead
- [zed](https://github.com/ocaml-community/zed) -- this looks more full featured, and more flexible, but will likely be a bit more involved to use

Answer (score 2):

I made a library to abstract over the Linenoise library to provide `readline` functionality. It also provides features to wait until delimiters are entered before accepting input.

ocamline: https://github.com/chrisnevers/ocamline